# JNA : program does not get terminated.. hangs at some point at jna source

Tags: java, jna

I am trying to solve the following problem for days. My JNA program gets hanged while execution of particular native function and debugging shows program control gets lost at particular location in JNA Source. Here are the details.
I have three native functions in DLL which I am trying to access with JNA.
    They are as follows

```
DllExport long calculatePayment(...,Protection   protectionArr[PROTECTION_SIZE],
    Others   othersArr[OTHERS_SIZE],RC  rcArr[RC_SIZE], ...);  
DllExport long bufferCalculatePayment(const char *inputBuffer, char **OutputBuffer); 
DllExport long fileCalculatePayment(const char *InputFile, const char *OutputFile);
```

Corresponding Java interface mapping is as follows

```
public interface DLLInterface extends Library {

public DLLInterface INSTANCE = (DLLInterface) Native.loadLibrary("DLLInterface",   
DLLInterface.class);
/* Others Structure is as follows.. protection and rc structure is similar with their   
own initialize methods*/

public static final NativeLong othersSize = new NativeLong(20);

class Others extends Structure {
    public static class ByValue extends Others implements Structure.ByValue {
    }
    public double amt = 0.00;    
    public NativeLong flag = new NativeLong();     
    public byte[] details = new byte[50]; //
    public byte[] mDetails = new byte[50]; 
    public NativeLong flag2 = new NativeLong();    

    public static Structure[] initialize() {
        Others result = new Others();
        Others[] resultArr = (Others[]) result.toArray(othersSize);
        return resultArr;
     }

    public void setDetails(String dataIn) {
        Arrays.fill(details, (byte) 0);
        if (dataIn != null) {
            String data = dataIn;
            if (data.length() > 49) {
                data = data.substring(0, 49);
            }
            byte[] bytes = data.getBytes();
            System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, details, 0, bytes.length);
        }
    }

 //other set functions here    
@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {      
return Arrays.asList("amt", "flag", "details", "mDetails", "flag2");        
 }

}
//Protection and RC sturcutre are similar. Both structures contain fields    
             of the type byte[] and double.
//Prototypes for native functions       

 NativeLong calculatePayment(.....Structure[] protectionArr, Structure[]   
 othersStruct , Structure[] rcArr,.....) ;

 Nativelong bufferCalculatePayment(Strubg inputBuffer, PointerByReference 
 OutputBuffer); 

 Natuvelong fileCalculatePayment(String InputFile, String OutputFile);

}

//In main function I am calling these functions as follows - 
public static void main(String args[]){
 DLLInterface.Others[] othersArr = (DLLInterface.Others[])    
 DLLInterface.Others.initialize(); 
 DLLInterface.RC[] rcArr = (DLLInterface.RC[]) DLLInterface.RC.initialize(); 
 DLLInterface.Protection[] protectionArr = (DLLInterface.Protection[])   
 DLLInterface.Protection.initialize();  //static method
         ...
         //passing values to structures
         ...
     //few native functions calls goes here (they get executed   successfully

 NativeLong y =  
 DLLInterface.INSTANCE.calculatePayment(....protectionArr,othersArr,rcArr, ...);

 String inputBuffer = ""<?xml version= \"1.0\" ?><ROOT><REQ><TRANSACT> 
 <ID>12345</ID><METHOD>COMPOUND</METHOD><AMT>50000</AMT><TERM>360</TERM></TRANSACT>  
 </REQ></ROOT>";

 NativeLong b = DLLInterface.INSTANCE.bufferCalculatePayment(inputBuffer,pRef);

 DLLInterface.INSTANCE.fileCalculatePayment("InFile","OutFile");

 }
```

For all three functions program gets hanged..never get terminated so I tried to debug the code. Then I found that after invocation of
Object result = invoke(args, nativeType, allowObjects) , program control gets lost in after following for loop. I listed few lines of source code from 
Function.java file source- JNA source

```
public Object invoke(Class returnType, Object[] inArgs, Map options){
.......
result = resultConverter.fromNative(result, context);
    ....
// Sync all memory which might have been modified by the native call
    if (Structure.ByReference[].class.isAssignableFrom(inArg.getClass()))
    {   Class type = inArg.getClass().getComponentType();  
                Structure[] ss = (Structure[])inArg;
        for (int si=0;si < ss.length;si++) {
         Pointer p =array.getPointer(Pointer.SIZE * si);
         ss[si] =Structure.updateStructureByReference(type, ss[si], p); 
    }  //////*///////////////////////*/program control gets lost after this
}.........}
```

What could be the problem any guesses? Is there something wrong with native functions or my mapping of arguments is incorrect.
Any help is much appreciated..

Comment: Did you write the Java code yourself? If so, try generating it with JNAErator (https://code.google.com/p/jnaerator) and see if the generated code differs from yours.

Comment: @Jukka, I tried with both and result is the same...

Comment: If you truly have no `Structure.ByReference[]` usage in your code, there's no way you could get into the quoted code block that you say is looping.  Either you're lying to us, your debugger is lying to you, or there's some code running that you're unaware of.

Comment: @technomage : Why should I lie? I am not here to test anybody's knowledge. I have high regard to all fellow programmers and moderators.

Comment: That was just a way of saying that what what you were saying was not necessarily what was actually happening, I wasn't out to destroy you :)